# Bat file issues

Tags: windows, batch, git, python, batch-file

I'm trying to setup a discord server and downloaded the project from Git but there's a file named as runbot.bat which is necessary to run and when I run it i get the error:

> 'REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v HideFileExt 2>nul' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>   =ValueValue was unexpected at this time.

runbot.bat:

```
@ECHO off

CHCP 65001 > NUL
CD /d "%~dp0"

SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SET KEY_NAME="HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced"
SET VALUE_NAME=HideFileExt

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1-3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY %KEY_NAME% /v %VALUE_NAME% 2^>nul`) DO (
    SET ValueName=%%A
    SET ValueType=%%B
    SET ValueValue=%%C
)

IF x%ValueValue:0x0=%==x%ValueValue% (
    ECHO Unhiding file extensions...
    START CMD /c REG ADD HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced /v HideFileExt /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
)
ENDLOCAL


IF EXIST %SYSTEMROOT%\py.exe (
    CMD /k py.exe -3.5 run.py
    EXIT
)

python --version > NUL 2>&1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO nopython

CMD /k python run.py
GOTO end

:nopython
ECHO ERROR: Python has either not been installed or not added to your PATH.

:end
PAUSE
```

Comment: I can't repro this.

Comment: looks like a syntax error in FOR LOOP for IN should be the index IN(start,incr,end) containing numbers, I think....  then DO contains the command Reg Query ....

Comment: @TonyStewart No, it's correct. Its extracting three values (name/type/key value) from the reg query. `HideFileExt REG_DWORD 0x0` on my system.

Comment: Hacker Red - How about breaking the batch FOR loops apart and running each manually from a command prompt one-by-one to see which one is causing you errors... I see a few things with your script that I would change if I wrote it to be proactive but that's my word of advice, break it down, run it in the parts it is manually setting you variables, etc. and the FOR loops, and start troubleshooting this way.... it's the best way to learn as well. I too see the setting of the variables from the first FOR loop works as expected for the expected values there `HideFileExt REG_DWORD 0x0` in my system.